# Gulp TypeError: dest.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack, require

I'm trying to generate a bundle.js file with a Gulp task

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    wrench = require('wrench'),
    conf = require('./webpack.config'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');

// Webpack
gulp.task('wp', function() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/scripts/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack(conf))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/build1'));
});
```

However, I get `TypeError: dest.on is not a function` when I try to run it:

[image]

Here's the folder directory:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error occurs because webpack doesn't work natively with gulp streams. Naturally the returned object by `webpack()` doesn't include `dest.on` which is specific to gulp.

Either use [gulp-webpack](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream) or follow the official docs on how to use [webpack with gulp](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html)

Sample code taken straight out of the official docs which uses `webpack-stream`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: I have the `dest.on` TypeError even with `webpack-stream` :(

Comment: @RomanM.Kos Just tried my example again. Works fine with latest `gulp`, `webpack` and `webpack-stream` packages.

Comment: I've upgraded my packages and this does not seem to be doing the job.

Comment: I had this working in one VS 2017 project but not another. The compare showed that in one I was piping with perens and not in the other. 

Working `tsProject.src().pipe(debug()).pipe(tsProject()).pipe(debug()).pipe(gulp.dest...`
NonWorking `tsProject.src().pipe(debug).pipe(tsProject).pipe(debug).pipe(gulp.dest..`